# Data transfer in Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have 2 web application that the databases are azure sql.

1. 1st web is used to record all payment and internal business rule
2. 2nd web is used to capture request payment from external vendor

I'm planning to transfer data between both databases and there will be job execution for some interval time.

Usually, I use SSIS but in this case all databases are in the cloud environment. I don't have any idea:

- how to transfer data between 2 database in the cloud.
- how execute job (scheduling) for push & pull data, synchronizing.

please, tell me a brief simplest process to do data transfer in Azure (reference/link/keyword), then I will explore by myself.

Comment: Well, I think I just found the keyword Data factory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) and databricks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-extract-load-sql-data-warehouse). But I still don't know which one I have to choose ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the word "synchronizing" if you are looking to transfer data between the 2 databases to keep them synchronize then you should consider using [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) to synchronize group of tables between databases with a sync frequency of seconds, minutes, hours, or days.

For incremental data load you can consider using [slices](https://medium.com/@benhatton/how-to-construct-time-slices-of-your-data-for-azure-data-factory-4977c2a85cde) in Azure Data Factory (ADF) as explained [here](https://www.dutchdatadude.com/implementing-incremental-data-load-using-azure-data-factory/). With ADF you can use a [watermark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) column for incremental loading